# Error During Deployment of an Application via AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm encountering an unusual error while deploying the latest code for my application.

This is an old application and I've deployed many versions before this error.

Even redeploying the last working version is failing with the same error.

The current version made changes to a few twig files as well as updated the composer.json and composer.lock files wit the latest DB version.

PHP 7.1
Symfony 3.3
aws ec2, s3, rds

**Here is the EB UI error:**

Application deployment failed at 2020-10-28T16:34:04Z with exit status 1 and error: EBExtension in .ebextensions/composer.config failed. 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 317: invalid start byte.

**Here are the log errors:**

***EB Activity Log***
Using configuration value for DocumentRoot: /web
[2020-10-28T19:06:03.996Z] INFO  [3029]  - [Application deployment app-4419-201024_163347@118/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-10-28T19:06:04.606Z] INFO  [3029]  - [Application deployment app-4419-201024_163347@118/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars

***EB Command Log***
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.372Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_site_prod] : Completed activity.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.378Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_site_prod] : Starting activity...
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.379Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_site_prod/Command 01updateComposer] : Starting activity...
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.768Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_site_prod/Command 01updateComposer] : Activity execution failed, because: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 317: invalid start byte (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

[2020-10-28T12:30:06.768Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_site_prod/Command 01updateComposer] : Activity failed.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.768Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_site_prod] : Activity failed.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.768Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Activity failed.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.797Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Activity failed.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.797Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2020-10-28T12:30:06.797Z] INFO  [3547]  - [Application deployment app-ed2c-201028_081818@111] : Completed activity. Result:
Application deployment - Command CMD-SelfStartup failed

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by AWS using Composer 2 (latest version).

I added "self-update 1.10.10" to our deployment configurations to make AWS use an older Composer version (see below).

commands:
01updateComposer:
command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.10.10